# Scala: Concatenate two immutable Lists

Tags: list, scala, concatenation, immutability

I was trying to figure out how can I get an List with user input back using tail recursion and then adding this "temporary list" to an finalList and retrying this again and again, but fore some reason I can't figure out why my code isn't working?

EDIT: Here is an update to the working sample solution!

```
  val finalList = List[String]()


  def exerciseSelector(finalList: List[String]) {
    val user = scala.io.StdIn.readLine("choose:")
    user match {
      case "add" =>  exerciseSelector(finalListAdd(finalList,addToList(List[String]())))
      case "print" => println(finalList) ; exerciseSelector(finalList)
      case "stop" => sys.exit()
    }
  }

  def addToList(acc: List[String]): List[String] = {
    val input = scala.io.StdIn.readLine("input:")
    input match {
      case "stop" => acc
      case input: String => addToList(input :: acc)

    }}

def finalListAdd(acc: List[String], list: List[String]): List[String] =  list match{
    case Nil => acc
    case h :: t => finalListAdd(h :: acc, t)
  }

exerciseSelector(finalList)
```

Comment: Can you tell us more what is not working exactly? (Exception or log result would be neat)

Comment: The problem is, if I am "add"-ing things to the list it seems to work pretty fine, and as soon as I enter "stop" to get back to the exerciseSelector() and then try to print out the finalList, it is printing me out an empty List.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be wrong, I haven't tried it myself but I would guess that `addToList` never have the opportunity to return the accumalated list.

At the moment you say "stop", you call `exerciseSelector()` before returning the `acc` value.

Also, the result of `finalListAdd` seems to be lost somewhere. It should probably be given as argument of `exerciseSelector()` to be able to be printed.

Can you try that please?

```
 def exerciseSelector(finalList: List[String]) {
    val user = scala.io.StdIn.readLine("choose:")
    user match {
      case "add" =>  exerciseSelector(finalListAdd(finalList,addToList(List[String]())))
      case "print" => println(finalList)
      case "stop" => sys.exit()
    }
  }

  def addToList(acc: List[String]): List[String] = {
    val input = scala.io.StdIn.readLine("input:")
    input match {
      case "stop" => acc
      case input: String => addToList(input :: acc)

    }}

def finalListAdd(acc: List[String], list: List[String]): List[String] =  list match{
    case Nil => acc
    case h :: t => finalListAdd(h :: acc, t)
  }

exerciseSelector(List[String]())
```

The change being `exerciseSelector()` has moved up into its `exerciseSelector()` self.
And finalList is given as argument of `exerciseSelector()`. A default value given at first call.

Comment: hmm yes that was also my thought about the code, that he couldnt give back the list... I will check it out, thanks!
EDIT: I just tried it out and this doesn't work since its recursive then and needs a result type...
But anyway I tried to run the addToList only and added where the case is Null an println before it is giving back the acc and it is working just fine, so thats not the problem

Comment: This code doesn't work too since the exerciseSelector() would then need an result type too and here you have no result type declared at the exerciseSelector function!!
EDIT: I just adjusted the function exerciseSelector with an return value and now its working but whenever you try to call the "add" case again after the first time, the finallist is getting overwritten which should not be

Comment: I don't think ```exerciseSelector``` has to return anything. ```finalList``` is printed inside

Comment: . (True I could remove ```=``` in the signature)

Comment: Would you mind putting your updated code somewhere please?

Answer (score 1):

First of all

```
val tempList = List[String]()
val finalList = List[String]()
```

Are unnecessary, as you cannot really add to these lists, they are both immutable and *final* vals.

`finalList` returns a `List[String]` that (as far as I can see) should be the list that you want to print.

However, the result of

```
case "add" => finalListAdd(finalList,addToList(tempList))
```

is never used anywhere.

I am not sure about the specific requirements, but actually I believe you code can be reduced to

```
  @tailrec
  def exerciseSelector(currentList: List[String]): Unit = {
    val user = scala.io.StdIn.readLine("choose:")
    user match {
      case "stop" => sys.exit()
      case "print" =>
        println(currentList)
        exerciseSelector(currentList)
      case "add" => exerciseSelector(currentList)
      case input: String => exerciseSelector(input :: currentList)
    }
  }

  exerciseSelector(List.empty)
```

Here, the *'add'* case is redundant.

The code will add any string not matched otherwise to the list.

On 'print' it will print out the current list.

And only on 'stop' it will exit.

Comment: Thank you for your solution! Your way is also very interesting. 
I dont have any specific requirements, I was just trying to figure out how to add something to an list do something different in the meanwhile like printing it out and then again adding something to an list without loosing the previous content added to the list, and without using mutable lists!